# JPEG compression: Implementing Huffman coding

Tags: image-processing, encoding, jpeg, huffman-code

I'm working on implementing an JPEG encoder, thats supposed to support exactly one JPEG format:

- baseline JPEG
- 3 channels (Y, Cr, Cb)
- 4:2:0 subsampling
- interleaved mode

I finished the first steps (color conversion, subsampling, DCT, quantization and zig-zag reordering) and now im stuck with the Huffman coding.

Say i have a really small image which is 32x16 pixels. That would result in two MCUs, where each MCU is encoded like here:
[image]

Having two MCUs my array of values before Huffman coding looks like this:

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+------+
| Y00_0 | Y10_0 | Y01_0 | Y11_0 | Cb_0 | Cr_0 | Y00_1 | Y10_1 | Y01_1 | Y11_1 | Cb_1 | Cr_1 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+------+
```

where each cell consists of 1 DC value and 63 AC values.

I'm struggling to apply Huffman coding to these values. As far as i know before the actual Huffman coding DPCM is applied to DC values while RLE is applied to AC values. But is it an internal step of a modified Huffman coding used in JPEG or it is some actual preprocessing that can be done before?

Also, do i have to encode every 8x8 block indepentend of each other or do i combine all DC values into a stream and all AC values into another stream and apply the RLE over multiple 8x8 blocks of AC values?

Comment: The DC an AC prefix codes are interleaved in entropy coded segments. It might help to look at an existing encoder or decoder. For example [this one](https://github.com/xbarin02/jpeg).